# Override default compile task in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT, `compile` task does the compilation of the project code and `test:compile` does compilation of the project's tests. I want a single `compile` task which does both. I want to override the default `compile` task and dont want a task with a new name (because want to enforce compilation success of all tests with every code change to project's main code). Am using Build.scala (not build.sbt) and tried the method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482456/add-task-to-build-scala) SO answer. My trial is pasted below and does not work because the return type of the `compile` task is `TaskKey[Analysis]`. How should I change this?

```
val compileInTest = TaskKey[Analysis]("compile the tests")

compileInTest := {
  (compile in Compile in <module-name>).value
  (compile in Test in <module-name>).value
}

lazy val projectA = Project(
  "a",
  file("a"),
  settings = hwsettings ++ Seq(
    compile := compileInTest
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define alias in `.sbtrc` file:

`alias compile=test:compile`

which will do both tasks.